# MySQL ORDER BY with numeric variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I can't undestand how I can pass UNSIGNED parameter to MySQL procedure to proceed ORDER BY like this:

```
DECLARE orderColumnNumber UNSIGNED;
SET orderColumnNumber = 1;

SELECT *
FROM users 
ORDER BY orderColumnNumber;
```

If I execute:

```
SELECT *
FROM users 
ORDER BY 1;
```

It works properly, but with variable is not.

upd:

This didn't work too:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM users 
    ORDER BY CAST(2 AS UNSIGNED);
```

Comment: You can't, unless you use dynamic SQL.  The value has to be a constant.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff But how it works with Rand() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the point. What you are looking for is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users 
ORDER BY columnName    -- Here you provide the column name by which you want to sort
LIMIT orderColumnNumber ;
```

ie, in ORDER BY you provide the column name by which you want your data to be sorted. As far as what I understood you want to LIMIT your data based on the variable which you have declared.

When you provide `orderColumnNumber` in the ORDER BY then it is interpreted like a column name and hence it does not work as you want.

Now the point that why it is working for ORDER BY 1 then the [SQL standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) has the answer to it which says:

> ```
> 10)If ORDER BY is specified, then each <sort specification> in the
>         <order by clause> shall identify a column of T.
>
>         Case:
>
>         a) If a <sort specification> contains a <column name>, then T
>           shall contain exactly one column with that <column name> and
>           the <sort specification> identifies that column.
>
>         b) If a <sort specification> contains an <unsigned integer>,
>           then the <unsigned integer> shall be greater than 0 and not
>           greater than the degree of T. The <sort specification> iden-
>           tifies the column of T with the ordinal position specified by
>           the <unsigned integer>.
> ```

**EDIT:**

If you want to use the variable as you commented you can try like this:

```
SET @orderColumnNumber := 1;
SET @sql:=CONCAT('SELECT * FROM users Order BY ',@orderColumnNumber);
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

Comment: No, I do not want to use LIMIT or sort by column name, but column number. I want to sort with <unsigned integer>, which is contained in a variable.

Comment: @Stabilitronio:- It is [not recommended](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal) first of all and even if you want to do that then you have to use the dynamic SQL. You can refer this: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/12/27/sql-server-order-by-columnname-vs-order-by-columnnumber/

Comment: @Stabilitronio:- Updated my answer!

Comment: Yeah, I also think about prepared statements too, it is ugly, but it works. Thank you for your help. In my opinion it is strange behavior of MySQL with order by <ordinal> in variable :-/